# How to text display in the same cell without color in jspdf

Tags: jspdf, jspdf-autotable

- How to displays different colors within a cell just like in the
  picture.
- The table is generated with jspdf-autotable.
- I didn't find a related method in the docs.

Here is my code.
`

```
doc.autoTable({
    startY: contentHeight,
    html: `#${key}`,
    theme: 'grid',
    styles: {
      font: 'SourceHanSansCN',
      fontStyle: 'normal'
    },
    columnStyles: {
      0: {cellWidth: 'wrap'}
    },
    pageBreak: 'auto'
```

`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QQnD.png)